# Perfect image links parser

Tags: php, html-parsing

I'm parsing image links from external webpages in my php script. This is my pattern:

```
$pattern = '/<img[^<>]+?src=["\']([^<>]+?)["\']/';
```

I found tags like this in some pages:

```
<img class="avatar-32" src="<%= avatar %>" />
```

That's why the `[^<>]` And I don't know how to get other potencial error tags

So I wanted to know, how to perfect my pattern to accept just the valid img tags.

There are questions like:

1. Can there be spaces between `src` and `=` and `"` ?
2. Between ´<´ and `img` ?
3. Even newlines?
4. What if I find a `'` in src attribute?

In fact how browsers parse links?

Note: I didn't add extensions because the links can be:

```
http://www.example.com/img.jpg?1234
http://www.example.com/img.php
http://www.example.com/img/
```

Also I have a relative to absolute link converter. So the conversion is not the problem

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regexes. As you're finding out, it's impossible to do consistently/accurately/reliably. Use DOM instead. ALL of your questions go away once you start using DOM operations.

Comment: [Obligatory post to this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/383609). On a more helpful note, use the [PHP DOM](http://uk3.php.net/dom) library

Comment: This is a solved problem. People have already written, tested and debugged code that handles this already. Whenever you have a programming problem that others have probably had to deal with in the past, then look for existing code that does it for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). It has many and useful functions to find links, textContent, manipulate dom and more.

For example to get the urls of images:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($response); //I assume that you're reading/curling pages

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
    if ($node->hasAttribute('src')) {
        $url = $node->getAttribute('src');
        //Also you can do some regex here to validate urls 
        //and bypass those like "<%= avatar %>"
        echo $url,'<br>';
    }
}
```

These methods can also be very usefull

```
$node->nodeValue //To get the textContent of the node
$node->childNodes //To get the children of the node. It will return a nodelist object 
                  //as getElementsByTagName('img')
$node->nodeType // Some nodes returned when calling childNodes are textnodes
                //so they can be bypassed with a conditional:
                //if( $node->nodeType == 1){//It's an element node}

$nodes->length // length of a nodelist object 
$nodes->item(1) // 2nd node of a nodelist
```